# The natural map from the tensor algebra to the symmetric algebra has a section?

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

If $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over a field of characteristic zero, and $\pi$ is the projection from $T^n(V)$ (the $n$-fold tensor product) to $S^n(V)$ the $n$-fold symmetric product, I'm asked to show that $\pi$ has a section.

My initial thought was that since $T^n(V)$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, and the projection $\pi$ is a surjective linear transformation, we have that there exists a right inverse of $\pi$ (i.e. a section). This seemed too simple to be true and didn't require any knowledge about tensor algebras. Am I missing something?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a particularly nice section that is probably what is being asked for; in particular one which is $GL(V)$-equivariant. But whoever asked you this question should have been more precise.

Comment: Out of curiosity what does that section look like?

Comment: @Jon: send a monomial $v_1 \dots v_n \in S^n(V)$ to $\frac{1}{n!} \sum_{\pi \in S_n} v_{\sigma(1)} \otimes \dots \otimes v_{\sigma(n)}$ (the need to divide by $n!$ is why the problem specifies characteristic zero). The image of this map is called the space of symmetric tensors and as a $GL(V)$ representation it's isomorphic to the symmetric power (in characteristic zero).

Comment: This map induces a map of graded vector spaces.